# How to reference custom resource-file in xml

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

How does you register a custom xml-resource-file with android studio so that you can reference it from other xml files?

I understand that its possible to call values from new resource values programmatically using R but I was wondering if there was a way to do that statically from another XML file.

For example, referencing that new file (in this case called keys.xml) in another xml file

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@keys/MAPS_API_KEY" />
```

as opposed to using strings.xml

**Edit:** It turns out that @string does *NOT* specifically reference strings.xml. I was originally under the impression that it did and knowing that know makes my question seem a tad silly.

Comment: The question is not at all clear. Are you talking about a file like a layout file or just the data ?

Comment: @gaurav4sarma a new file similar to strings.xml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a resource file like:

keys.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="testKey">TEST_VALUE</string>
</resources>
```

In code, you can call:

```
getString(R.string.testKey);
```

From another xml:

```
<TextView
...
android:text="@string/testKey"
...
/>
```

The trick is you declare as a `<resources>` in your xml file.

Comment: I meant specifically referencing the file from another xml file. For example, you can call @string/{resource_name} to use items in values/strings.xml. I apologize, I'll edit my question to try and make it clearer

Comment: But the file is yours? I mean, Have you created the file and want to access from others XML ?

Comment: Thanks! I was always under the impression that @string/ was specifically referencing strings.xml.

Comment: At the start, I felt that impression too, hahaha! so I've been search a lot before figure out that @strings is for a all resources.